# Accessing webpage through url without displaying it?

Tags: javascript, html

So I don't know if javascript has this function, or it is not possible due to security reasons. I am new to javascript, so it may sound dumb...

What I want to achieve is (making a most simplified case): I have two html files, I will call them "current page" and "target page" respectively.

Say the "current page" looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a id="link1" href="target.html">Target</a>
<a id="link2" href="target2.html">Target</a>
\\And it goes on... say 1000 more links
</body>
</html>
```

And the "target page" looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img id="image1" src="resource to be collected.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way similar to document.getElementByID, that enables me to write a script which collects all the resources in the "target page"?

In other words, can javascript "open" a link in the page without visibly opening the link, and then run the script on the "opened" link?

Comment: You're looking for the wonders of AJAX.

Comment: Might be using `iframe`

Answer (score 0):

I personally use jQuery for AJAX, but use an AJAX call to the target page and

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].outerHTML = ajaxOutput;
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn AJAX, you use JavaScript to respond on click and then send request to another page with GET or POST methods without refreshing the page. The returned response is then added dynamically to the DOM element wherever you want.
Here is an code sample from w3schools.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above example external data is loaded from a .txt file without refreshing the page.
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP
This will help you get started.
Here is another great example that I believe you should start with
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started